# Replace single quote with double quote in a column in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

My dataframe in R has a column A where I have string data with single quote in it.

```
Column A
'Hello World'
'Hi World'
'Good morning world'
```

What I would like to do is to replace the single quote with double quotes and achieve the output like below.

```
Column A
"Hello World"
"Hi World"
"Good morning world
```

Can this be achieved?
Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: `gsub("'", '"', x$A)`?

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of the example.

Comment: @akrun, what do you mean by dput?

Comment: I meant `dput(head(yourdata[["Column A"]]))`, get the output.  This will allow us to reproduce the example

Comment: Sure, it look like this: IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G2,'Previous Week''s Data'!A:A,1,FALSE)),'Yes','No').  It is basically a formula.  I want to replace all of 'Yes' with "Yes" and all of 'No' with "No".  I provided a simplified example at the beginning of the question to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

"iris" is a sample data frame and I am trying to replace single quotes of "Species" column. Since ' and " are special characters within strings hence they are specified using escape sequences:

`iris$Species <- gsub("\'","\"", iris$Species)`

Comment: @VishalPandya glad to know that, you may check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)